# seg fault during printf on variable I just set

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, printf

So I'm seg faulting when I call printf in the following situation.  I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?  Thanks a million.  I've marked the spot in the code where i get the seg fault with a comment (in the first chunk of code).

```
...
    char* command_to_run;
    if(is_command_built_in(exec_args, command_to_run)){
        //run built in command
        printf("command_to_run = %s\n", command_to_run); // <--- this is where the problem is
        run_built_in_command(exec_args);
    }
...

int is_command_built_in(char** args, char* matched_command){
    char* built_in_commands[] = {"something", "quit", "hey"};
    int size_of_commands_arr = 3;
    int i;
    //char* command_to_execute;
    for(i = 0; i < size_of_commands_arr; i++){
        int same = strcmp(args[0], built_in_commands[i]);
        if(same == 0){
            //they were the same
            matched_command = built_in_commands[i];
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the pointer `matched_command` by value. Therefore it isn't changed by the call to `is_command_built_in`. So it retains it's uninitialized value.

Try this:

```
char* command_to_run;
if(is_command_built_in(exec_args, &command_to_run)){   //  Changed this line.
    //run built in command
    printf("command_to_run = %s\n", command_to_run); // <--- this is where the problem is
    run_built_in_command(exec_args);
}


int is_command_built_in(char** args, char** matched_command){   //  Changed this line.
    char* built_in_commands[] = {"something", "quit", "hey"};
    int size_of_commands_arr = 3;
    int i;
    //char* command_to_execute;
    for(i = 0; i < size_of_commands_arr; i++){
        int same = strcmp(args[0], built_in_commands[i]);
        if(same == 0){
            //they were the same
            *matched_command = built_in_commands[i];   //  And changed this line.
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thats what I was looking for. I knew I was doing something wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: is what I had originally just saying it was only initialized in the scope of the is_command_built_in function, and when it returned to the main program it seg faulted because it hadn't been initialized in that scope?

Comment: Correct. In the original version, when you passed it into the function, it makes a copy of the pointer into the local scope. Therefore, when you assign to it, it only changes the local copy. When you finally exit the function, that local copy dies. And you're left with the original value which is uninitialized and invalid.

Comment: that all makes sense to me, but even now when I make the suggested changes i get a seg fault on the line "*matched_command = built_in_commands[i]". I think something else is going on there that I'm not aware of

Comment: Did you change `char* matched_command` to `char** matched_command`? I forgot to mark it in my answer. Though it shouldn't compile if you didn't make that change.

Comment: maybe I don't understand completely then. WHy do i need to change it to ** instead of just * ?

Comment: `**` is pointer to pointer. So what does is that you're passing the address of `command_to_run` into the function. Since `command_to_run` is of type `char*`, it's address will be of type `char**`. Then in the function, you write to this address - thereby modifying the original copy.

Comment: Can someone give me an example of how I can do this using malloc instead?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`command_to_run` is uninitialized.  The call to `is_command_built_in` could as easily have crashed.  Such is the nature of undefined behavior.